# OOZIE Spark Action : Getting No such method error sometimes

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, oozie-workflow

I'm getting this exception while executing spark action via ooze. Some time job runs fine and some time I get this exception. Really weird, not sure why it's happening.

I have check versions of spark jar in both oozie lib and my application jar and it's same(No conflict)

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.setSQLConfGetter(Lscala/Function0;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$.setSQLConfGetter(Lscala/Function0;)V
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:950)
```

Any suggestions what could be causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This clearly indicating jar conflict. I have faced the same issue.

But as you said you have verified that there are no conflict. So there is one possibility I could see is **[Dependency Conflicts](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)**

If that is not the case,
I suggest try generating a jar for once with all the dependencies included. When you use a jar with all the dependencies included, the JVM will locate the dependencies directly from the jar, so there will not be any mismatch due to a different library version. In maven, you can generate a jar with all the dependencies by using the [assembly](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) plugin.